# How to prevent a Sharepoint 2010 application from Globally Deploying?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a Sharepoint 2010 application that consists of Sharepoint application pages and donot contain any web parts. So when I deploy the wsp of the application from the central administration the application will be globally deployed. I want avoid this and deploy the application on to a particular site. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Can you use module for storing Application page and Deploy this solution as Sandbox Solution.
    Sandbox solutions are not stored in File System(Physical path) and assemblies can't be deployed to Global Assembly Cache(GAC). But it's available on C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\UCCache at runtime. Note the ProgramData is a hidden folder.